# instance.save() is not saving the model in ListSerializer Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In Django Rest Framework ListSerializer when I want to save the validated data to the database by calling instance.save() I'm getting an error saying **queryset object has no attribute save**.

ListSerializer class:

```
class NoAccessDetailsListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):

    # This will be called when there is list of objects
    #here instance is list of queryset and validated_data is the list of json object
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):

        ret = []
        for index, data in enumerate(validated_data):

            #checking if row is already chosen
            if(instance[index].row_chosen):

                # do not update the info to db
                # just append the data to ret
                ret.append(instance[index])

            else:
                instance.id = instance[index].id
                instance.row_chosen = validated_data[index].get(
                    'row_chosen')
                instance.user_working = validated_data[index].get(
                    'user_working')

                ret.append(instance)

                instance.save()

        return ret
```

Serializer Class

```
class NoAccessDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):


    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=False)

    class Meta:
        model = NoAccessDetails
        list_serializer_class = NoAccessDetailsListSerializer
        fields = ("id", "row_chosen",
                  "user_working")

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.id = instance.id
        instance.row_chosen = validated_data.get(
            'row_chosen')
        instance.user_working = validated_data.get(
            'user_working ')

        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Basically in ListSerializer I'm checking if the row is chosen already in the DB. If True then I just append the instance data to a dictionary else I want to update the data to the DB and append the updated data to a list and return it.

Here in the ListSerializer I'm passing filtered queryset from the APIView class as instance and validated_data is a list of validated data.

Sample JSON data which I will pass to the APIView class:

```
[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "row_chosen": true,
            "user_working": "John"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "row_chosen": true,
            "user_working": "David"
        },
]
```

When I pass the JSON data, it will properly filter out the rows from DB and pass the queryset as instance and JSON data to the serializer class.

```
# here list_of_id is the ids which are there in the JSON object. i.e [1,2]

filtered_id_data= NoAccessDetails.objects.filter(
                id__in=list_of_id)

            serializer = NoAccessDetailsSerializer(filtered_id_data,
                                                   data=request.data,
                                                   many=True,
                                                   )
```

The ListSerializer update() is working but when it runs else block and tries to update the data it gives me an error **queryset object has no attribute save**. Whereas in the serializer's update() it runs the instance.save() and updates the data for the single object. I'm not sure where I'm making the mistake.
Please help me with this.

**Update:**

I changed instance.save() to instance[index].save() in ListSerializer class. Now the **queryset object has no attribute save** has been fixed. Even though when I use instance[index].save() I'm unable to save the data in the data base.

**Models:**

```
class NoAccessDetails(models.Model):
    20 CharFields
    ...
    ...
    user_working = models.ForeignKey(
        UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    row_chosen = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=10)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user_email = models.EmailField()
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Here in the NoAccessDetail model, I've kept user_working null true because the data to this model will be coming from a different source. Initially while importing the data the user_working will be null. While updating the data from an API call, I'm validating the JSON data.

Comment: It is a ListSerializer, so the instance here is a list i.e. a queryset, not an instance or object.

Comment: Yes it is a list of queryset. <QuerySet [<NoAccessDetails:>, <NoAccessDetails: >]>

Comment: @Mehran am I wrong anywhere, Could you please correct me?

Comment: Basically you need to loop through the instance (since it is a list) and call the .save() on each item :). I have posted an answer citing the code in the docs

Comment: I tried instance[index].save() but this time it will not give me any error but instead, it will not save the object in database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call the .save() method, you have to call it on an instance of a Model, not on a QuerySet of the model. According to DRF Docs,

```
class BookListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
  def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    # Maps for id->instance and id->data item.
    book_mapping = {book.id: book for book in instance}
    data_mapping = {item['id']: item for item in validated_data}

    # Perform creations and updates.
    ret = []
    for book_id, data in data_mapping.items():
        book = book_mapping.get(book_id, None)
        if book is None:
            ret.append(self.child.create(data))
        else:
            ret.append(self.child.update(book, data))

    # Perform deletions.
    for book_id, book in book_mapping.items():
        if book_id not in data_mapping:
            book.delete()

    return ret
```

You can see they are using a book_mapping. This is creating a dictionary where the key is the book's id and the value is the instance of the book.

Hope this helps!

**EDIT**
Check the line just below the 'else:' block. You see you need to use .get() to get the object of the model you want to update, and then use the .save() method.

**RE-EDIT**
Using instance[index].save() should also work. I think you need to call obj.save() before appending to ret.

```
class NoAccessDetailsListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        ...
        ...
        else:
            obj = NoAccessDetails.objects.get(id=instance[index].id)
            # or obj = instance[index]
            obj.row_chosen = validated_data[index].get(
                'row_chosen')
            obj.user_working = validated_data[index].get(
                'user_working')

            print('Instance data ',
                  obj.row_chosen,
                  obj.user_working)
            obj.save() # call this before appending to ret
            ret.append(obj)


    return ret
```

**RE-RE-EDIT**

I updated the snippet according to docs.

```
class NoAccessDetailsListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):

# This will be called when there is list of objects
# here instance is list of queryset and validated_data is the list of json object
def update(self, instance, validated_data):

    ret = []

    obj_mapping = {obj.id: obj for obj in instance}
    data_mapping = {item['id']: item for item in validated_data}

    for obj_id, data in data_mapping.items():
        obj = obj_mapping.get(obj_id, None)
        if not obj:
            continue

        if obj.row_chosen:
            ret.append(obj)
        else:
            obj.row_chosen = data['row_chosen']
            obj.user_working = data['user_working']
            obj.save()
            ret.append(obj)

    return ret
```

Comment: In my code I'm doing like this  NoAccessDetailsSerializer(filtered_id_data,
                                                   data=request.data,
                                                   many=True
                                                   )

where filtered_id_data is the queryset. Instead of passing the queryset what I need to pass?

Comment: Sure! Let me know if it worked! I personally have never really bothered using ListSerializer and always stuck with ModelSerializer or basic Serializer (if not connected with any Model)

Comment: And wanted to know if you had a list of objects which needs to be updated how would you do? In the documentation itself, they have mentioned to go with the ListSerializer.

Comment: hey @Mehran the above code actually worked. But still, instance[index].save() is not saving the data in the database. Whereas in the update() in ModelSerializer saves the data by calling instance.save(). Do you have any idea?

Comment: For a list, I would loop through the validated_data list in my view and call the modelserializer for each item.
I checked the ListSerializer implementation in the DRF serializers.py file.
For the update method:
`Serializers with many=True do not support multiple update by default, only multiple create. For updates it is unclear how to deal with insertions and deletions. If you need to support multiple update, use a ListSerializer class and override .update() so you can specify the behavior exactly.`
So, no I am kinda confused since the writers themselves are not clear about this.

Comment: @AashayAmballi you are using enumerate on validated data. This will create problems in mapping your object instance (not the list) with the appropriate validated data. Please refer to the docs and fix this.

Comment: @AashayAmballi I updated my answer according to the docs, see if it helps!

Comment: Yeah I will try and let you know. :)

Comment: Hey @Mehran I tried what you suggested. Since in my model the user_working field has a foreign key relationship with a custom user model, the user_working field is not getting saved in the database. But the row_chosen data is getting saved :(

Comment: in the user_chosen you are passing the name. Just pass the 'id' of the user. Something like this: `obj.user_working_id = data['user_working_id']`

The data being passed:
`[{"id": 1, "row_chosen": false, "user_working_id": 33},]`

Comment: I'm actually passing the id of the user. Just for demonstration purpose, I had mentioned the user name.

Comment: I actually did obj.user_id = data["user_working"].user_id and also this obj["user_working"] = data["user_working"].user_id. It even prints out the user id as well. But when it saves, it saves None. I have no idea what's going wrong! row_chosen data is getting saved but user_working is not.

Comment: Here data is a json. It should not contain the 'user_working' object, but rather a to_string representation sent by the client side. You have to pass the id from the client side.

Comment: Yes  @Mehran , data is a json object when it comes to ListSerializer the user_working key will have user model instance as value

Comment: Hmm. could you provide your model definition please?

Comment: Hey @Mehran! I don't know really, all of a sudden it started working fine. Now the user_working and row_chosen data are getting saved in the database. Thank you, my friend. Really much appreciated for helping me throughout this issue. Thank you :)

Comment: which model definition? User or NoAccessDetail?

Comment: NoAccessDetail model. Also please check if the object you're passing in the update method to the field user_working is a User object.

Comment: Yes it's an user instance. And NoAccessDetail model is kinda huge. It has many fields. Where can I share you the model?

Comment: I've updated the question with the model definition for both NoAccessDetails and UserProfile.

Comment: @Aashay Amballi Oh it's already working! I was really since it shouldn't Not work xD. Nice solving a weird problem together! And please up vote my answer if possible :)

Comment: Yes my friend... Really much appreciated for solving this issue with me. Thank you 

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200157/discussion-on-answer-by-mehran-instance-save-is-not-saving-the-model-in-listse).